# Android Code Injection

Tags: android, android-ndk

Creation of a hidden process seems to be impossible ... so i came to conclusion that hiding a process from the user is impossible **so if the service or process appears to RUN as a sub process to any other applications like PHONE APP , or MESSAGING APP , the running process can be hidden to an extend .**

This can be only achieved by code injection , so want a help in achieving this . code injection from the user level.

Comment: Is this for an upcoming android virus project ?

Comment: Why do you need to achieve this? The ability to do this would be ripe for exploitation if possible.

Comment: its just part of my exploration .... :)

Comment: Well, if you do manage to achieve this, remember to report it as a security issue to Google so they can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, this is impossible, short of a security flaw as @Dave notes.

No respectable developer tries to hide processes from users or inject code into foreign processes, as seems to be your intent.

Answer (score 7):

Sure this is possible - http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=68&id=6#article. And as for @commonswear's answer, that's completely wrong. Many respectable developers do this type of this for good, in fact some rooting techniques work this way. Also, sometimes developers can do this to their own code post-deployment, and some developers may do this and notify the user because it provides extra functionality that they wanted in the first place.